# Move/Scale/Rotate Edge to Create New Faces?

Tags: modeling

From 3ds Max, it would be the equivalent to selecting an edge holding shift and then doing the operation (move/scale/rotate) and new faces would be created using the selected edges. Is there something similar to that in Blender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pressing <kbd>E</kbd> to Extrude, immediately press <kbd>S</kbd> to Scale or <kbd>R</kbd> to Rotate. Moving/Grabbing along the face normal is the default behavior after extruding, as you probably know. Scaling and rotation happens relative to whatever [Pivot](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/pivot_point/index.html) method you are currently using.

Also, you might benefit from knowing about click-extrusion. To do this hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and LClick where you want the vertex, edge, or face to be extruded to. The angle of the originally selected geometry gets repositioned to make the extrusion smoother.